# QGIS Measure Distance Using Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, vector

I have a point shapefile with 80K+ records.  Shapefile is projected in wgs84.  The shapefile contains fields with the latitude and longitude of the point.  I need a new field that contains a distance from a known point (Point B) in each record.  Point B is the same for every record in the shapefile.  There is a distance function in the field calculator (field calculator -> geometry -> distance).  But I can't make sense of the syntax.

Example:

```
distance( geom_from_wkt( 'POINT(4 4)' ), geom_from_wkt( 'POINT(4 8)' ) ) → 4
```

What I want to do is measure the distance from the geometry of the current point to the geometry of a point I supply (for example point at "25.906543, -80.546800").  How do I refer to the current record using that tool and how to a create the new geometry?  Is is something like:

```
distance( geom_from_wkt( 'POINT(25.906543, -80.546800)' ), 
($geometry ) )
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the tool `distance matrix`? If so, how does it not suit your needs? Also, distance calculations using the field calculator in QGIS are done in the CRS of the layer, so based on a WGS84 layer you'd get distance in degree.

Comment: Disclaimer: I have experience with ESRI software, so I my comments might use ESRI-specific terminology.  Distance matrix might work.  If I understand it correctly, it will create a new table with fields for the unique id of the "from" table and one with the calculated distance.  I could then join those tables on the unique ID and then calculate the distance into a new field in the "from" table.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I went with babel's solution because it added a field with the distance.  I didn't have to create another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
length(make_line(make_point(25.906543, -80.546800),$geometry))
```

you create a line (`make_line`), starting at the point with your fixed coordinates (created with the command `make_point(25.906543, -80.546800)`) and ending at the second point, defined with `$geometry` as the current point of your layer. You then measure the length with the expression `length()`
If you create a new field with the field-calculator, you get a new field containing the distances for each point of your layer to the point at 25.906543, -80.546800

Comment: Nitpicky question: what dictates what units the length is in?

Comment: The CRS of your layer: check the CRS settings for the units used

Comment: That worked.  Thanks for the response.